# Will a temporary table inside a stored function be built more than once when the function is executed from a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql, database

Let's say I have a function that creates a temporary table which I want to use for a `SELECT` query. Any chance that the function will rebuild the temporary table more than once in a `SELECT` statement? What's the best practice in this scenario?

```
CREATE FUNCTION getID(id INT)
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  -- build ID table
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tbl2(
    id int,
    val int
  );

  -- insert values into tbl2 here

  SET @id = NULL;

  SELECT tbl2.id INTO @id from tbl2 where id = tbl2.id;
  return @id;
END
```

```
SELECT getID(id)
FROM tbl
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: No. All calls will be performed in the same connection, so the table will exist for all calls except the first one.

Comment: You can enforce it, but what's the actual question? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: The function will be called `x` *  `Rows`. Having said that, MySQL does not allow creating dropping tables nor `selecting` within a function. Stored procedure however deos allow this

Comment: @Nae I want to run the function in a query, but I don't want the temporary table to be rebuilt every time I have to run the function.

Comment: @J.Chan Okay but still. Why would you need that?

Comment: @Nae do you mean the temporary table or the function?

Comment: @J.Chan Whichever. How do you want to transform the table you have? What are the example input & output tables?

Comment: @Nae let's say I wanted to store values about `tbl` based off one of its columns to perform more complex queries. Therefore I want the temporary table to store values that I can use. For example, having `tbl2` contain a `set_id` for each row on `tbl` depending on a datetime value on `tbl`.

Comment: It is not a good practice to put the queries into a function as this will serialize the query when the function is called for each row (no join agaist the `tbl`). If you have complex logic you should instead consider creating a stored procedure where you put the logic and the queries.